# Unknown column in 'where clause

Tags: mysql

I've read almost every single thread around the net about the Unknown column 'dfsd' in 'where clause 
the dfsd is the string that I entered through a html form using the post method..
the php file(where the forms data are being sent) just checks if the line above is an existing user name.

```
function authCheck($usr,$psw){
print $usr;

mysql_real_escape_string($usr);
$sql = "select usrNameMarket from marketusr where usrNameMarket=$usr";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$records=mysql_num_rows($result);  //elenxw gia eggrafes

        if($records){
                $queryData=mysql_fetch_array($result);  

                if($queryData['usrNameMarket']==$usr){
                    $usrNameChk="ok";
                }       

                else{
                $usrNameChk=null;
                }

        }

        else{
                $usrNameChk=null;
        }
rest of the file ....
```

I get the error from MySQL telling me the column doesn't exist (although the value has been passed correctly, that's why I used the print function just to double check it)...

I add the single quotes:

```
$sql = "select usrNameMarket from marketusr where usrNameMarket='$usr'";
```

Then I get a syntax error when mysql_query executes...

Then I tried

```
$sql = "select usrNameMarket from marketusr where usrNameMarket='".$usr."'";
```

Still I get the same syntax error.

I don't know what is wrong I've tried everything... 
Is it possible that I get that error because of the database structure or scheme or the data type of that field(which is varchar)?

Comment: Shouldn't you do `$usr=mysql_real_escape_string($usr);` on first lines?

Comment: You're syntax in the second code area seems to be correct for me. Are you sure, it's in this line? You can see it in the error message. "Unkown column" error appears, if there is no column with this name in the table you want to use ... You could also add a `var_dump($sql);` in the line before `$result = ...` and send us the output.

Answer (score 0):

Use `marketusr.usrNameMarket` instead of just `usrNameMarket`

Comment: He is only using the table `marketusr`, so shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @fedorqui Well, he claims he's tried everything this is just another idea.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
$sql = "select usrNameMarket from marketusr where usrNameMarket='$usr'";
```